# Getting the resulting URL in Next.js server side component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side

I'm writing a server-side component in Next.js to be used in both the current stable version (12) and the new beta version (13). I need to determine what the resulting URL path will be on the page that uses the component. How can this be accomplished (again, in a server-side component, not a client-side component.)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I wanted to know the same thing, since server side components doesn't have getServerSideProps, I am unsure how to do this in the experimental "app" directory in nextjs version 13.